# Using Google Play Games services without google developer account

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is that possible to implement some features like real-time multiplayer by using Google Play Game services without developer console?

Comment: I have not tested it, but I highly doubt it. Atleast not in any way that I would officially recommend.

Comment: @Marcus that's just unlogical. I'm develeloping app for educational purposes and i should pay 25$.

Comment: You can distribute your APK without publishing it on Google Play, but then I'm pretty sure you can not use Google Play Games. I guess the guys over at Google have to provide as much as you and me :-)

Comment: @Marcus the problem is that i don't want to publish it anywhere. I'm only learning to use these services in my very simple Ping Pong game which looks like two paddles and one ball. I want to add online multiplayer mode to it and some achievements like "Win 10 times", "First victory"and so on.

Comment: @nikoliazekter Google spends a considerable amount of time developing these tools and provides servers that are used for multiplayer free of charge to registered developers. But if you don't want to do that it's fine, you can spend the time and write the networking code for yourself, setup some servers and host the multiplayer games ;)

Comment: @free3dom seems very easy. I know about all that stuff but it would be cool if Google provided testbed to learn how to use that things without paying 25$.

Comment: @nikoliazekter for learning you are better off writing your own, that's part of learning - only reason you would **need** GPGS is for publishing on the Play Store and then $25 is really nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart) you have to "set up the game in the Google Play Developer Console" as step 2 instruct you to. I do not see any other way, if you do not want to implement all functionality yourself.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  There is not currently a way to access Play Game Services without access to the Google Play Developer Console, which requires a developer account.